# additive vs multiplicative quiver/hypertoric varieties - properties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory, holomorphic-symplectic, quiver-varieties, symplectic-resolutions

It is a standard fact that a smooth Nakajima quiver variety / hypertoric variety $X$ has the following properties:

1. It is holomorphic symplectic $(X,\omega)$, in fact 1'. hyperkahler
2. It has a projective map $\pi: X\rightarrow X_0$ to an affine Poisson variety.
3. There is a $\mathbb{C}^{*}$-action on $X,X_0$ making $\pi$ equivariant.
4. This action contracts $X_0$ to a point, thus contracts X to central fibre $\pi^{-1}(0)$
5. It acts with positive weight on the symplectic form $\omega,$ $t\cdot \omega=t^{k>0} \omega$. 5' In addition, when quiver does not have loops/hyperplane arrangement has no coloops, there is an action with $k=1.$

I am wondering how many of these properties $1-5'$ remain (partially) true for their multiplicative counterparts, i.e. multiplicative quiver / hypertoric varieties?